# Laravel Passport cannot assign client because field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, laravel-passport

I'm following a tutorial from [this](https://youtu.be/oJCImQWfCCM?si=hUmfQfURVdqn0lyN&t=523) at that exact time, he can easily create a laravel passport client without getting error

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `oauth_clients` (`user_id`, `name`, `secret`, `provider`, `redirect`, `personal_access_client`, `password_client`, `revoked`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, Client 1, 9V1jO3TZAGYBwX0cSjhb6BxELxicvYcocnEcUwTn, ?, http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback, 0, 0, 0, 2024-03-08 03:54:17, 2024-03-08 03:54:17))
```

and I definitely know why I am getting this error after checking the table structure created by laravel passport.. because the field `id` it doesn't have a default value neither an auto increment because it's a `char` type field. it's all from laravel passport and I don't change a single design of their tables.

I'm simply execute `php artisan passport:client` and answer each question following the tutorial, but I'm getting error above.

any idea?